# Insert Existing TreeNodeCollection in TreeNode

Tags: vb.net, insert, treeview, treenode, treenodecollection

### Problem:

In the screenshot below, I have a node `300-9885-00X` along with its TreeNodeCollection (in the red square). A little bit lower, we find the `300-9885-00X` again, I want to insert the TreeNodeCollection that we found earlier, into that node ...

[image: TreeView Nodes]

---

### Background Information

I have a recursive program that goes through AutoCAD / SolidEdge assemblies. It opens the documents and prints the assemblies, and their children, and so on (recursively) ...

- Green color means it is printed
- Orange means it has already been printed before, so we don't need to print it again...

---

### Question:

How do we **insert an existing TreeNodeCollection** into a **TreeNode**?

*Knowing:*

1. The location of the TreeNodeCollection
2. The location of the node in which I want to insert the collection into

The following variable `TreeNodes` contains my collection. Must I loop through the collection in order to add its text?
[image: TreeCollectionAdd Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a `TreeNodeCollection` to a Node. You must **loop** through the `TreeNodeCollection` and add the nodes individually like so:

```
For j As Integer = 0 To TreeNodes.Count - 1
    n.Nodes.Add(TreeNodes(j).Clone())
Next
```

Notice I used `.Clone()`. This is due to the insertion of an already existing node. You can't do that, you must either delete the existing one or clone it. In my case, I had to clone it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the '_NodesCollection' from the '_parentNode' TreeNode.
TreeNodeCollection _Nodes = _parentNode.FirstNode.Nodes;

// Create an array of 'TreeNodes'.
TreeNode[] Nodes = new TreeNode[_Nodes.Count];

// Copy the tree nodes to the 'Nodes' array.
_Nodes.CopyTo(Nodes, 0);

// Remove the First Node & Children from the ParentNode.
_parentNode.Nodes.Remove(_parentNode.FirstNode);

// Remove all the tree nodes from the '_parentNode' TreeView.
_parentNode.Nodes.Clear();

// Add the 'Nodes' Array to the '_parentNode' ParentNode.
_parentNode.Nodes.AddRange(Nodes);

// Add the Child Nodes to the TreeView Control
TvMap.Nodes.Add(_parentNode);
```